# How to automatically hyphenate before sending to a device?

Tags: calibre, hyphenation

Is there a way an ebook gets converted to [azw3](http://www.openthefile.net/extension/azw3) **and** hyphenated when I press "Upload to device" button in Calibre?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with azw3, but can't you resize the font while reading? Wouldn't that change the hyphenation?

Comment: @beaker it's not azw3 format but other languages with words longer that in english you are not familiar with :)

Comment: Fair enough, but 1) shouldn't that context be in the question, and 2) that still doesn't address what happens when the font size is increased to the point that the pre-hyphenated words no longer fit on a line.

Comment: @beaker should it? The question is not about why do I need hyphenation, but about how to do it.

Comment: @beaker has a good question. Why won't you answer it? In order to hyphenate you need to format pages, and that depends on the current font size when reading.

Comment: @beaker My answer is apparently not satisfactory for the OP. But does
it answer your concern regarding the interaction between hyphenation
and font size variation?

Comment: @babou Of course, soft hyphenation is the solution to the resizing problem. Had the OP been a bit more forthcoming about their work flow then perhaps they would have gotten more relevant answers. No skin off my nose.

Answer (score 3):

Hyphenating a text that is not in a fixed presentation (page shape, or
ratio page size/ font size) makes little sense as the words may change
position on a line.  Hence, I am assuming that what you are asking is how
to automatically do [soft hyphenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen#Text_to_be_formatted_by_the_recipient), so that the reader of the file can
modify the font size and still get proper hyphenation where needed.

Soft hyphenation consist in marking with a special character
(e.g. SHY) all the places in the text where a word can be hyphenated.
Then the displaying device does not have to know hyphenation rules,
which vary from language to language, and can simply use the markers to
cut words when needed, which may vary depending the fonts chosen by
the reader.

Can this be done by Calibre. I never had to do it myself, but Calibre
does have a plugin that will do it. It is called **Hyphenate This!**
and works for AZW3 and for EPUB. It is described in some details in
this [article of the-ebook-reader.com](http://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2015/04/29/how-to-add-hyphen-support-to-kindles-for-better-readability/)(with a [download address](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=126512&d=1407482048)), and is also discussed on [mobileread.com](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2456847). It can also be [downloaded from Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Office/Calibre-Plugins/Hyphenate-This-98046.shtml).

From what I have seen in the files, the whole code is in Python, so it
is likely to be platform independent (Mac, Linux, Windows).

Now, if the question was whether soft hyphenation can be done without pushing an extra button, I cannot answer. But the OP does not seem very willing to add more details to his question.

Comment: I know about that plugin but it doesn't convert **and** hyphen (it was bold selected in the question!) and upload in one click.

Comment: @SmitJohnth If you knew about that plugin, you should have said so.  In a good
question one is supposed to state what one already knows about the
issue.  That makes the question more precise and saves time for
everyone. You also did not bother clarifying that you mean soft
hyphenation, which was apparently not understood. ----- Afaik, the ebook
converters are implemented as plugins, like much of Calibre
functionality. **Hyphenate This!** is also a plugin. So the answer to
your question is **yes**. You simply have to merge the two plugins
into a single one. Should I add this to my answer?

Comment: Well, an anwser *answers* the question and your answer haven't did it. Yes, I meant soft hyphens, english is not my native language. Is there a way to merge 2 plugins in one and still have all the functionality and settings from both?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Regarding the merge of two plugins,  I have no experience. Theoretically, it is always possible. In preactice, the two concerned plugins seem sufficiently close that it should be possible. They both transform an e-book from one form into another. Seem to be the kind of thing that can be pipelined. The main problem is getting into Calibre as it is a sizeable piece of software.